# Integration multi dimension exp function

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I faced this problem, i tried to write it in 1 dimension. Thanks for any help.
$$ \int_{{R}^d}e^{t^T\alpha}t^T\alpha e^{-\gamma ||t||^2}dt~~where~~ t,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^d ~~~\gamma \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: Hi, please provide some work and at which point you got stuck :)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let introduce integral 
$$
I(\lambda)= \int_{{R}^d}e^{\lambda t^T\alpha} e^{-\gamma ||t||^2}dt\,.
$$
You integral is a derivetive of this one. In fact it is a Gaussian integral. You can modify it in the following way
$$
I(\lambda)=\int_{{R}^d}\exp\left[-\gamma ||t-\frac{\lambda}{2\gamma}\alpha||^2+\frac{\lambda^2}{4\gamma}||\alpha||^2\right]dt\,\\=\frac{\pi^{D/2}}{\gamma^{D/2}}
\exp\left[\frac{\lambda^2}{4\gamma}||\alpha||^2\right]
$$
You result is a $I'(1)=\dfrac{1}{2\gamma}\dfrac{\pi^{D/2}}{\gamma^{D/2}}
\exp\left[\dfrac{1}{4\gamma}||\alpha||^2\right]$